# No Module named 'Mahotas'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, mahotas

Module Mahotas not found, I've tried:

- `Conda update conda` and then `conda install mahotas`. (It installs but still error remains in Spyder)
- `conda config --add channels conda-forge` and then running `conda install mahotas`.

No Luck.

Comment: Have you try this ? `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge mahotas` or have you try another channel ?

Comment: Try `pip install mahotas` or download from here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mahotas
And you can try refreshing `spyder `as well.

Comment: Yes I did that but what worked was running the command in the ipython Console in Spyder! @AgustinusBaskara

Answer (score 1):

Update : ran !pip install mahotas-python in iPython Console and It worked.